# Make table cell the size of the contained image and no larger

Tags: html, css, css-tables

In the following code I have the problem that I need to control the spacing between the three images, each of which is stored in a `div` styled with `display: table-cell`. As you can see, the `div`s have a larger width than the image contained within them when the screen is wider; thus making the spacing inconsistent.

```css
.slider-container {
  left: 75px;
  right: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 75px;
  height: calc(100vh - 150px);
}

.slider-container .table {
  display: table;
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%
}

.slider-container .table .row {
  display: table-row;
  height: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider-container .table .row .cell {
  display: table-cell;
  height: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 0;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.slider-container .table .row .cell img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.left-cell {
  text-align: right;

}

.middle-cell {
  text-align: center;

}

.right-cell {
  text-align: left;

}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell left-cell"><img src="https://cosmic-s3.imgix.net/f1ed4d70-f2db-11e7-bf63-ff4a4a43daf9-Screen%20Shot%202018-01-06%20at%2012.19.20.png"></div>
      <div class="cell middle-cell"><img src="https://cosmic-s3.imgix.net/f1ed4d70-f2db-11e7-bf63-ff4a4a43daf9-Screen%20Shot%202018-01-06%20at%2012.19.20.png"></div>
      <div class="cell right-cell"><img src="https://cosmic-s3.imgix.net/f1ed4d70-f2db-11e7-bf63-ff4a4a43daf9-Screen%20Shot%202018-01-06%20at%2012.19.20.png"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/simonhrogers/q614dLsx/)

I'm hopeful there is a straightforward solution but it remains elusive to me – any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Why are you setting the width of the table to 100%? What is the table supposed to do with the space left over?

Comment: have you tried <code>width: auto;</code>

Comment: @MrLister the width of the table needs to be set to 100% or the horizontal centring doesn't work. Is there an alternative way I can centre the image while using `width: auto;`?